# MQTT payload from script

Tags: c, arduino, printf

I have this code for compose and send MQTT payload.

```
snprintf_P(mqtt_data, 
  sizeof(mqtt_data), 
  PSTR("{\"" D_JSON_SYNC "\":%d,\"" D_JSON_LOW "\":%d,\"" D_JSON_HIGH "\":%d,\"" D_JSON_DATA "\":\"%06X\",\"" D_CMND_RFKEY "\":%s, \"" D_TOPIC "\":%s}"), 
  sync_time, 
  low_time, 
  high_time, 
  received_id, 
  rfkey, 
  Settings.mqtt_topic); 
MqttPublishPrefixTopic_P(6, PSTR(D_RFRECEIVED));
```

You can see "Settings.mqtt_topic" is the value for "topic" included in message.

this is mesage received

```
{"Sync":12230,"Low":390,"High":1190,"Data":"596F91","RfKey":1, "Topic":10101019}
```

And I have this another code for MQTT payload.

```
snprintf_P(mqtt_data, 
    sizeof(mqtt_data), 
    S_JSON_COMMAND_INDEX_SVALUE, 
    D_CMND_RFKEY, 
    sonoff_bridge_learn_key, 
    D_LEARNED); 
MqttPublishPrefixTopic_P(5, PSTR(D_CMND_RFKEY));
```

this is message received

```
{"Rfkey1":Learned}
```

Can somebody give me an approach to get "topic" included in the payload in the second code?

I need to receive message like this

```
{"Rfkey1":Learned, "Topic":10101019}
```

I have tried several ways without success.

I tried something like this

```
snprintf_P(mqtt_data, 
  sizeof(mqtt_data), 
  S_JSON_COMMAND_INDEX_SVALUE, 
  D_CMND_RFKEY,
  D_TOPIC,
  sonoff_bridge_learn_key, 
  D_LEARNED, 
  Settings.mqtt_topic);
```

Comment: Show us what you've already tried. Also there is not enough context here to actually help.

Comment: i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be just using `snprintf` (doc [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/))

This takes 3 initial arguments

1. Output buffer
2. Size of the output buffer
3. A format string to use to build the output

The arguments following these 3 are the values to be inserted into the format string. You can not just add extra values on the end without updating the format string with where to put them and what format they should take.

You have not included the format string for your second example so I can't suggest how to edit it.